# iOS: create a link button

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile-safari

I want to create an IBAction for a button, that when you push it, the app go in background and at the same time open safari at a specific link (example "www.google.it")
Can you help me?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Inside your IBAction method, include the line

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use interface builder :

Create a UITextView and not a UIButton, write the link as text to textview and select the links checkbox in the interface builder. It will become the link you want at run time.

Answer (score 2):

using swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)
```

or swift 3.0

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://google.com")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *okbutton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *canel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfiled;
- (IBAction)okButtonClick:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)CanelButton:(id)sender;



- (IBAction)okButtonClick:(id)sender {


    NSString *searchString = textfiled.text; // UItextField.text
    NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalString]];



}
```